# Symfony - Ajax request update not working

Tags: json, ajax, symfony, fullcalendar, droppable

I'm trying to update a Task with FullCalendar using the draggable and the droppable.
I'm doing an ajax request when we drop a task to update it. I sent the good task to my controller :

```
 eventDrop:function(info) {
                let start=moment(info.event.start).format('YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm');
                let end=moment(info.event.end).format('YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm');
                $.ajax({
                    url:"{{path('update_tache')}}",
                    data: 'start='+start+'&end='+end+'&id='+ info.event.id ,
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function(json) {
                        console.log(json);
                    },
                    error: function(request, error){
                        console.log(request);
                        alert(error);
                    }
                });
            },
```

I tried to update this task here :

```
/**
 * @Route("/tache/modifier_tache_from_agenda", name="update_tache")
 */
public function update_tache(Request $request, ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $tache = new Tache();
    $start = new DateTime($request->query->get('start'));
    $end = new DateTime($request->query->get('end'));

    $repository = $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('App:Tache');

    $tache = $repository->find($request->query->get('id'));

    $tache->setDateDebut($start);
    $tache->setDateFin($end);

    $repository = $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('App:EtatTache');
    $etatsTaches = $repository->findAll();

    $repository = $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('App:Projet');
    $projets = $repository->findAll();

    $form = $this->createForm(TacheType::class, $tache, array(
        'etatsTaches' => $etatsTaches,
        'projets' => $projets
    ));

    if ($tache) {
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $tache = $form->getData();
        $manager->persist($tache);
        $manager->flush();
    }

    return $this->json([
        'tache' => $tache
    ]);
}
```

I don't see any error in the json returned (I moved the task from 9th december to 25th december) :

```
{
"tache": {
    "id": 5,
    "label": "en attente",
    "dateDebut": "2019-12-25T01:00:00+00:00",
    "dateFin": "2019-12-26T01:00:00+00:00",
    "description": "en attente",
    "projet": {
        "id": 1,
        "nom": "aaa",
        "description": "bbbb",
        "etat": {
            "id": 2,
            "etat": "actuel",
            "__initializer__": null,
            "__cloner__": null,
            "__isInitialized__": true
        },
        "dateDebut": "2020-01-03T00:00:00+00:00",
        "siteWeb": null,
        "__initializer__": null,
        "__cloner__": null,
        "__isInitialized__": true
    },
    "etat": {
        "id": 3,
        "etat": "En attente",
        "couleur": "#FFA500",
        "__initializer__": null,
        "__cloner__": null,
        "__isInitialized__": true
    }
}
```

But, the task aren't updated in my database.

Comment: Please quote your code as in-line text, not via a link to an image. That makes it much easier to understand; and some people don't like following arbitrary links.

Comment: And also, images of code and data are basically useless to other users - they can be hard to read on smaller screens, the text cannot be searched, and it cannot be copied and pasted to use in an answer or demo. So you're just making it hard for people to help you! Also, for you it should be quicker to copy your code into here than to take a screenshot, upload it and make a link to it. I never understand why people think pictures of text are better than the actual text? Code is not graphics. Neither is data.

Comment: I edited my question to display the codes without images. I didn't think about that, sorry for that !